# Angular4 - Pass variable and Form Content to Service

Tags: angular, observable

I'm probably wording this wrong. I'm populating a `Client Form` with the response of an API in the `NgOnInit` function

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.indexForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(Validators.required),
      status: new FormControl(),
      logo: new FormControl()
    });
    this.activatedRoute.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => this.clientService.getClientById(params['id']))
      .subscribe((client: any) => {
        this.indexForm.patchValue({
          name: client.name,
          status: client.status,
          logo: client.logo
        })
      });
  };
```

The user is then able to modify the form, and re-submit it.

**Service Edit**

```
  editClientById(client:any): Observable<Client> {
    return this.authToken.patch('clients/' + client.id, client)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }
```

**Component Edit**

```
  editClientById(event): any {
    this.clientService.editClientById(this.indexForm.value)
      .subscribe( client => {
          console.log('Success! Save' + client)
        },
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  };
```

I'm console-logging it to test, but it is not working for obvious reasons. I'm passing the indexForm into the `editClientById` variable, which both seems proper, and improper to me.

The payload that is being responded with to the `ngOnInit` function is similar to that of 
`{id: 13, name: "fdsf", status: "dsf", logo: "dsf"}`
So to me `client.id` should exist. Presently, on click, I am provided with a 404 due to `clients\undefined does not exist` Meaning the ClientID isn't properly being passed.

Am I handling this improperly with Observables/models? Perhaps it's due to me not having the 'id' on the form?

**Update**

As expected, if I place a hidden field with the client ID, it does work - however, it's submitting the ID as a form value. Is there a more Angular-way of doing this, or is this the proper method?

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
this.indexForm = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl(Validators.required),
  status: new FormControl(),
  logo: new FormControl()
});
```

Is creating a data structure for the form containing each control along with its value. So something like this:

```
{name: "fdsf", status: "dsf", logo: "dsf"}
```

Note that the id property will NOT be there because it is not a control in the defined data structure. The names of the properties in the object above exactly match the names you give to the controls when building the form group.

I use code like this:

```
        // Copy the form values over the product object values
        let p = Object.assign({}, this.product, this.productForm.value);
```

To merge the original values (which includes the id) with the values from the form group data structure.

This line of code starts with an empty object (first argument). It updates the contents of that object with the product (second argument). It then overwrites any matching properties from the form (third argument).